# How to find probability winning twice in casino game?

Tags: probability

The game straight craps involves rolling two die. If you roll a total of 7 or 11 on the first roll you win. If you roll a total of 2, 3, or 12 on the first roll you lose. If you roll a total of 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10 on your first roll this number becomes your point. You continue to roll the dice. If you get your point before a roll of 7 you win. If you roll a 7 before your point total you lose. In straight craps you win a dollar for each dollar you bet.

Using theoretical probability what is the probability of an individual in a random game rolling a 5 on the initial roll and rolling another 5 before they roll a 7.

I calculated the probability of a 5 on the first roll which is 4/36. However, I am not sure of how to calculate the probability of getting a 5 on the second roll before a 7.

My answers booklet states that the possible outcomes are (4,3) (3,4) (1,6) (6,1) (2,5) (5,2) (1,4) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1)

But why are these the only probabilties? Why is (3,1) not a possibility out of all the possible rolls (which would be denominator, wouldn't it)? The probability of 5 on 2nd roll before a 7 is meant to be 4/10 according to my answer book.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "If you roll a total of $4,5,6,8,9,10$ on your first roll this number becomes your point." Do you mind further explaining what you mean by this? It's clearly not a "win" or a "loss" (as you've already defined those cases), so I'm not certain what it's supposed to accomplish.

Comment: @scoopfaze If your initial roll is a "point," you enter Phase II of the game.  In Phase II, you win or lose simply depending on whether you roll your "point" a second time before you roll a $7$.  All other rolls are irrelevant, and (to answer the question above) should therefore be excluded from the sample space because they don't affect the game's eventual outcome.

Comment: @RobertShore thanks, that helps clarify.

Comment: @RobertShore but why are rolls like (3,1) excluded from all the possibilities of second rolls that you can get? Isn't there still a chance of getting that? If so, why is it not included in the possible outcomes?

Comment: All the possible outcomes add to 7 or 5, is there a reason for that?

Comment: Because they're irrelevant to the final result of the game.  The only thing that matters is the relative probability of rolling your point or a $7$.  To put it in terms of conditional probability, given that your next roll is either your point or a $7$, what's the probability that it's your point?